# MeshTextureCoords element in DirectX .x file

Tags: directx, 3d-meshes

What is the significance of `MeshTextureCoords` element in a .x Mesh file?

Answer (score 1):

Don't they kind of make it obvious?
The name 'MeshTextureCoords' makes me think of Texture Coords of a Mesh.

Comment: How to specify the texture co-ordinates if the .x file does not have one?

Comment: The artist who creates the mesh needs to texture it, by applying sensible texture coordinates that map the texture over the mesh. While some primitives (cylinders, planes) can have texture coordinates automatically generated for them, if you have a complex mesh without texture coordinates, in general you won't be able to texture it sensibly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go way out on a limb here, and suggest that they specify [texture coordinates for the mesh](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb147194%28VS.85%29.aspx).